# Generics by context

Tags: c#, generics

*I started writing this as a real question, but I kept thinking of answers along the way, thought I would post it anyway to see if there were any other solutions*

I can think of two examples in which generics become an unecessary pain, and I wonder if there is a solution.

### Example 1

```
public class SomeClass<TDbConnection, TDbTransaction>
{
}
```

Now for any of us it's obvious - The DbTransaction, and DbConnection implementations will always be used in pairs - be it `SqlConnection` and `SqlTransaction` or `OracleConnection` and `OracleTransaction`

besides the fact that there is no way to make sure that the types make sense (nothing stops me from creating `SomeClass<SqlConnection, OracleTransaction>` when `SomeClass` uses three or four arguments that there types are inferable by context*, it becomes an unnecessary waste of time to instantiate each type.

*in this example, I am not sure how the framework can know, but you get my point? anyway the next example is more relevant

### Example 2

```
public interface IPoco<TKey> 
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
}

public class SomePOCO : IPoco<int> 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClassUsingPOCOAndId<TPoco, TKey>
    where TPoco : IPoco<TKey>
{
}
```

In this example I managed to force the use of the correct `TKey` in instantiation, but why can't I just call `new SomeClass<IPoco<int>>()` or `new SomeClass<SomePoco>()` I mean the `TKey` is inferable.

### Possible Solutions

I could drop the Generics, and in some cases it makes sense (like the first example). In others not so much, and creates either a memory or runtime overhead (unnecessarily creating of fields, or casting) or unnecessary code repeat.

The other solution I thought of was creating something like this

```
public interface IPoco<TKey> 
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
}


public class SomePOCO : IPoco<int> 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class PocoContext<TPoco, TKey>
   where TPoco : IPoco<TKey>
{
     TKey Key { get; set; }
     TPoco Poco { get; set; } 

     public PocoContext(TPoco poco)
     {
        Key = poco.Key;
        Poco = poco;
     }
}

public class SomeClassUsingPOCOAndId<TPocoContext>
{
}
```

This allows me to reduce the amount of code required for instantiation - but depending on my usage of the pocos - it could become really time consuming to create a context for each type.

Now I am wondering - isn't there a way to simplify this process? maybe by some sort of synthetic sugar? What would it take to implement it on C# 7 or 8?

Comment: On second sample - since class can derive from multiple interfaces compiler can't infer type in all cases. Otherwise adding interface to class would break existing code in surprising ways.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what it is you're trying to do. Seems you're trying to create arbitrary conventions (`IPoco<TKey>`) and then wondering about how can you avoid breaking them. Normally, if there is a good reason for a convention, it ends up being followed. If you want to enforce it look into lint analyzers, style enforcing etc. But i personally don't see any value in the `IPoco<>` interface from the sample code you provided.

Comment: The `IPoco<>` interface is just an example. The point is that when this structure makes sense, and it does imo (I prefer it over asp.net core returning `object` as Id for `UserManager<>` it becomes difficult to maintain.